# PDO Updating multiple records

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I know this question has been asked before and I've gone through many of the answers and am working off one of those [answers now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043967/updating-multiple-mysql-table-columns-using-arrays-with-pdo), however need some help with the following chunk of code.

```
<?php

$title = $_POST['title'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];

$A = count($item_name);

include ("connection.php");

try {

    $set_details = "UPDATE images
                    SET title = :title,
                    description = :description,
                    WHERE item_name = :item_name";


$STH = $conn->prepare($set_details);

    $i = 0;
    while($i < $A) {
        $STH->bindParam(':title', $title[$i]);
        $STH->bindParam(':description', $description[$i]);
        $STH->bindParam(':item_name', $item_name[$i]);
        $STH->execute();
        $i++;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo "I'm sorry, but there was an error updating the database.";  
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND);
}


?>
```

I get no errors upon execution and nothing is submitted to the mysql table, if you spot something please let me know, or if there is a better way to go about this could you point me towards a tutorial, I haven't worked much with PDO or multiple row updates yet.

Thanks in advance.

To Sam:

```
print_r($STH->errorInfo());
```

output was:

```
Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE item_name = '27'' at line 4 )
```

Comment: Does `print_r($STH->errorInfo());` output anything?

Comment: I added the error to the question there, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra comma after `:description`, it should be:

```
"UPDATE images
 SET title = :title,
 description = :description
 WHERE item_name = :item_name"
```

Comment: It's a very easy one to miss!